# How to determine a confidence interval without knowing mean and variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Currently I'm stuck at this point. We have sample size $n=100$ with sample mean $m=7.8$ and sample variance $s^2=4.0$. Now I have to determine a confidence interval around the mean with confidence $0.95$

I have to use central limit theorem to solve this but I don't know the mean and the variance which are necessary to determine the interval.

$$\left[\mu-1.96\, \sigma,\mu+1.96\, \sigma\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

For the computation of the confidence interval you have to use the sample mean and variance $m$ and $s^2$ (clearly, in general, you don't know the population's parameter).

Answer (score 0):

You are going to find the confidence interval? then for which values? I think, you need to know the mean value of the sample for which you are going to find out the confidence interval. Even for the simplest way to compute the confidence interval using student t-distribution, you need to have sample mean and standard deviation parameters.